# Как создать несколько инстансов одного микросервиса, с различным набором параметров?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tcp, микросервисы

я новичек в микросервисах, но у меня появился чисто архитектурный вопрос. Моя задача, сделать несколько подключений по tcp по разным адресам (их количество может быть различным), но бизнес логика для них практически одинакова. Вот и хотелось бы написать один микросервис для всего этого, но чтобы было возможно создать несколько его инстансов, каждый из которых подключался бы по своему ip адресу. Еще надо иметь возможность, если какой-либо из инстансов вылетел перезапустить его заново, а остальные бы продолжали работу как ни в чем не бывало. Или если в будущем добавится новый ip, при внесении его в список с ip-адресами (или еще куда, пока не важно) автоматически создавался бы новый инстанс. Возможно ли такое? И если да как это лучше организовать?